# Find index to first occurrence of the largest number

Tags: python

[image: Picture of the problem]

I also have to use a return statement.

Problem:

> Given a list of integers, return the index of the maximum number. If the maximum number is not unique, return the index of the first instance.

We can use `for i in range(len(input_list)):` to go through the list.

Comment: please provide the actual description of the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the title "Find index to the first occurrence of the  largest number" be more to the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def max_number_index(input_list):
    idx = 0
    max_number = input_list[0]
    for i in range(1, len(input_list)):
        if input_list[i] > max_number:
            max_number = input_list[i]
            idx = i
    return idx

print(max_number_index([0,1,2,3,4]))
print(max_number_index([-2,34,-43,0,5,9]))
print(max_number_index([2,3,3,3,3]))

4
1
1
```

You can, of course, use `for i in range(len(input_list)):` but I thought it unnecessary to follow the instructions exactly to the letter. In that case you look twice at the first item in the list, once to set initial values and then again in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
def largest(input_list):
    return input_list.index(max(input_list))
```

What we are doing here is finding the largest number with python’s built-in `max()` function.

Then we are finding the index by using python’s built-in `list.index()` function.

Finally we return it.

Example:

```
input_list = [0,1,2,3,4,4]
largest_number_index = largest(input_list)
print(largest_number_index)
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code would work -

```
input_list = [0,1,2,3,4,4]

def max_number_index(input_list):
    ans=0
    for i in range(len(input_list)) :
        if input_list[i] > input_list[ans]:
            ans = i
    return ans
print(max_number_index(input_list))
```

**Output :**

```
4
```

You just had to update the `ans` which stores the index of largest number till now. If current number has a value greater than  `input_list[ans]`, just update `ans` to current index value. At last, return the ans to get the correct index value of greatest element in the list.

---

A shorter version of the same code would be -

```
input_list = [0,1,2,3,4,4]

def max_number_index(input_list):
    return input_list.index(max(input_list))

print(max_number_index(input_list))
```